# Frequency dependence of permittivity -- why not monotonic?

Tags: optics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I naively thought that most materials were transparent to radiation of frequencies above their plasma frequency, and opaque to radiation below it. The most intuitive (and analyzed lightly in Griffiths' E&M book) reason I've heard is that opaqueness is caused by electrons in the material responding to the incident radiation by getting oscillated by it, in which they produce their own radiation that cancels the incident radiation. However, when the incident radiation is above the plasma frequency, they can't respond quickly enough and it can start to penetrate the material.

Mathematically, $\epsilon(\omega) > 0$ for $\omega < \omega_{plasma}$ and $\epsilon(\omega) < 0$ for $\omega > \omega_{plasma}$, and the wave vector $k \propto n \propto \sqrt{\epsilon}$, so when $\omega$ is above $\omega_{plasma}$, $k$ is imaginary and $e^{i \vec k \cdot \vec r}$ decays quickly in the material.

But I was recently told that as the frequency keeps rising, the material again at some point becomes opaque to it. What is this called, and what's the physical reason for it?

Answer (score 1):

The material may become opaque for radiation that has frequency close to resonance frequencies of the material. The electrons in matter are sensitive to radiation in certain ranges of frequencies (absorption peaks or bands) and can get excited. This is accompanied by stronger absorption of the radiation. The electrons are sensitive to certain resonance frequencies because they are bound in the metal and interact with nuclei and each other in a complicated way. The resonance frequencies and the function $\epsilon(\omega)$ can be calculated from a model that describes electrons in the metal and the interactions they experience.

Comment: Right, I forgot about band gaps and such. But does this effect still happen with metals, where the density of states is continuous?